# Help echoing array from php function

Tags: php, arrays, function, echo

Alright I am still learning my functions in php but this particular piece of code has me stuck. Credit goes to http://www.barattalo.it/2010/08/29/php-bot-to-get-wikipedia-definitions/ for the wikipedia query segment. I thought this looked interesting and am trying to use the code provided to echo data from the function. This is what I have:

```
<?php
    function wikidefinition($s) {
        $url = "http://wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=".urlencode($s)."&format=xml&limit=1";
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; he; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8");
        $page = curl_exec($ch);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($page);
        if((string)$xml->Section->Item->Description) {
            return array((string)$xml->Section->Item->Text, (string)$xml->Section->Item->Description, (string)$xml->Section->Item->Url);
        } else {
            return "blank";
        }
    }

    $define = wikidefinition("test");
    echo $define;

?>
```

however this simply echos "array" 
I know the code is getting to the if/else statement because if you change the input in "$define = wikidefinition("test");" to some random key combination such as "qoigenqnge" it will echo "blank" I cannot figure out why it is only echoing "array" instead of the data inside the array. Probably something stupid, but I have been reading up on arrays for a while and cant find any info. Any help will be great thanks!

Comment: please format your code, it only takes a minute and makes answering your question much easier.

Comment: My bad I forgot to do that. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
print_r($define);
```

instead of `echo` ?

Comment: That was exactly what I`m gonna say :)

Comment: ah good call, I had previously tried print_r but had set it up wrong. That worked but I know print_r is more of a debugging command, any way to get a result that looks a little nicer than this? eg. just the definition of test?

Comment: @jangoforhire sounds like what you want to echo is one of the elements of the array - after you've dumped out the array, look at the keys, and try echoing that. Something like echo $define['definition'];

Comment: Actually, you should probably just return the definition in your function if that is all you are looking for. No need to allocate an array if you don't need to :)

Comment: got it I was just looking at that now. Thanks very much for your help! Answer marked.